# How To Change Camera Field Of View From Python Script

Tags: python, rendering, camera

I'm trying to change the camera FOV by script. I've already seen different questions like this, but the answers doesn't work for me... This is my code:

```
import bpy
import math

a = 'hello'
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(enter_editmode=False, align='VIEW', location=(50,0,0), rotation=(1.57057,0.00174533,1.57057))
bpy.data.objects["Camera"].name = a
bpy.data.cameras[a].lens_unit = 'FOV'
bpy.data.cameras[a].angle= math.radians(10)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bpy.data.cameras` gives access to the camera data. And camera data is not renamed (stays 'camera.xxx') when you set the object name.

So, access the camera via objects and use its data:

```
import bpy
import math

a = 'hello'
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(enter_editmode=False, align='VIEW', location=(50,0,0), rotation=(1.57057,0.00174533,1.57057))
bpy.data.objects["Camera"].name = a
bpy.data.objects[a].data.lens_unit = 'FOV' #Access it by its object name
bpy.data.objects[a].data.angle= math.radians(10)
```

Additionally, you should not rely on the fact the created object is named "Camera" (because it won't if such a camera already exists).

You can:

```
import bpy
import math
from mathutils import Euler

a = 'hello'
camera_data = bpy.data.cameras.new(a)
camera = bpy.data.objects.new(a, camera_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(camera)
camera.location = (50,0,0)
camera.rotation_euler = Euler((1.57057,0.00174533,1.57057))
camera.data.lens_unit = 'FOV'
camera.data.angle = math.radians(10)
```